# Bootstrap hide tabs button in tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap tabs
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs
and I create hide button like this

```
<li role="presentation"><a href="#tab_content_6" id="tab_6" aria-controls="tab_content_6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"> Options &nbsp;&nbsp; <span onclick="$('#tab_6').hide();"  class="tab_hide_btn">X</span></a></li>
```

If I clicking the hide span, tab is opened and hidden at the same time, because both onclick action are on the same layer

Comment: Then what you exactly want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listner in your Javascript to hide tab:

```
$('li a[role="tab"] span').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).parents('li').hide();
});
```

Moreover Bootstrap provides an helper class to display a close button, so your html could be:

```
<li role="presentation">
    <a href="#tab_content_6" id="tab_6" aria-controls="tab_content_6" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        Options &nbsp;
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button> 
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try doing something like this in a `<script>` tag:

```
$('span').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parents('li').hide();
});
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/pekoduwusi/edit?html,js,output

I've updated jsbin with the functionality you're looking for. Its quick and dirty but does the trick. The concept is you want to get the `href` of the parent `span` then find the content with that `id` striping away the `#` character. Then, hide that content.

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cutiwibora/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This not working http://jsbin.com/kipidoduhu/edit?html,js,output. 
if I have an open Home tab and I click tab to close another, the content changes to the hidden tab

Comment: Blindly targeting all `span`s on the page is not recommended, even for a sample answer.